# How to intergate xtreme download manager with flashgot

Tags: download-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 14.4 and xtreme download manager is my default download manager. I know there is browser integration add on for it. but I want to integrate it with flashgot add on . I find xdm in flashgot options but it's useless no download starts only the main window pops up !

Comment: It might not be possible to do that because XDM uses Java as a foundation, I am not sure if Java apps like XDM can accept command-line parameters for starting a download. FlashGot sends paramters to start downloads. You could post a http://slexy.org paste of the --help output of XDM or you could use uGet instead. uGet has auto-integration with FlashGot. http://ugetdm.com

Comment: thank you for you kind reply. I found the solution by myself and it worked just perfect I will post the solution so that anyone can make use of it. I love U get but I hate the fact that I can't integrate it with Google chrome

Comment: it can,the Clipboard Monitor is plenty but we are working on making a chrome extension rebuild. However, you are using Firefox and FlashGot which integrates with uGet already so I am not sure what Chrome has to do with your decision.

Comment: @MichaelTunnell I was wainting for uget chrome extention for a long time man !

Comment: Ok I get that but you are now using xdm with firefox. Why not just use uGet with Firefox? That is what I don't understand.

Comment: @MichaelTunnell I use both of firefix and chrome so I need XDM to intergate with both of them . I asked about flashgot intergation with firefox and this doesn't mean I can do without chrome.. right???

Comment: I do without Chrome just fine. :) I see your point though. We are still working on the extension but spare time projects are not usually very quick. :) (I have 3 or 4 right now that I haven't touched in months unfortunately)

Comment: @MichaelTunnell please understand I really admire Uget and I think it's a good piece of software but the project needs to progress faster and find way to continue and mature .. It will be sad for me if the developer pulled the plug and killed the whole project .. this is the drama behind many promising open source programs !

Comment: the project is not our full time job so obviously we can't work on it constantly, we actually just released a brand new version with a while new major branch and a rebuilt core. We have been releasing beta versions like crazy, in fact we released 12 beta versions before uGet 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and i was not able to solve it using your method, i have found a different method that worked for me :

1. Firefox > Tools > Flashgot > More options
2. General tap > Press Add button > `XDM2` as name
3. Executable path : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`
4. Command line :`-jar /usr/lib/xdman/xdm.jar [URL]`

NOTE : The executable path may differ depending on witch Java version you are using.
Example : the Executable path for sun java 6 is : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.06/bin/java`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to integrate Xdm with flashgot:

1. from Firefox access tools menu → flashgot → more options.
2. from general tab press the `Add` button to add new download manger and enter a name.
3. browse to `/usr/lib/xdman` and select `xdman.jar` file
4. make the command line arguments template as "[URL]" then press OK.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox > Tools > Flashgot > More options

1. General tap > Press Add button > XDM2 as name

   2.Executable path -for this go to the folder where you have saved XDM and select java inside the folder `jre/bin`

   3.Command line arguments template : `-jar /usr/lib/xdman/xdm.jar [URL]`

Comment: http://xdman.sourceforge.net/ download from here xdm 2015